# React UseEffect - How to retrive selected array data and view that data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

**This is my JSON data File**

```
{
    "person": [

      {
        "id": "userId",
        "sellerImage": "https://i.pravatar.cc/300",
        "lastOnline": "Date of last online",
        "sellerName": "Ryann Remo",
        "isOnline": true,
        "lastSeenDate": "Today",
        "product":"Rough Shirt",
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfUser",
            "message": "Message text 01",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text 02",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": true
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message 03",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "id": "userId",
        "sellerImage": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50",
        "lastOnline": "Date of last online",
        "sellerName": "Karp Bonolo",
        "isOnline": true,
        "lastSeenDate": "Yesterday",
        "product":"Rough Shirt",
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfUser",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": true
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**This is how I'm imported that JSON data**

```
import AdminConversationData from "./AdminConversation.json";

const AdminConversation = () => {




  const person = AdminConversationData.person.map((data) => {
    return {
      ...data,
    };
  });

.....
```

**This is how I'm going to select a person in react file. (Using `onClick={() => setSelectPerson(idx)}` I'm going to select a person here using the IDX according to the below code I need to load that person's data to another place on this page.)**

```
<RadioGroup>
  <div className="space-y-2">
    {person.map((item, idx) => (
      <RadioGroup.Option
        key={item.id}
        value={item.id}
        onClick={() => setSelectPerson(idx)}
        className={({ active }) =>
          `${
            active
              ? 'ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-red-300 ring-white ring-opacity-60 border-l-4 border-red-500'
              : ''
          }
            relative rounded-lg shadow-md px-5 py-4 cursor-pointer flex focus:outline-none entry cursor-pointer 
            transform hover:scale-105 duration-300`
        }
        
      >
       
          <>
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/200"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">{item.sellerName}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">{item.lastSeenDate}</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-xs bg-red-500 text-white rounded-full h-6 w-6 leading-6 text-center inline-block">
              23
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
          </>
      
      </RadioGroup.Option>
    ))}
  </div>
</RadioGroup>
```

***(this is React headless UI radio group and I'm going to select a certain person here.)***

**In this place, I want to retrieve that person's data as an example the seller's name.**

```
<>
 <div class="relative">
    <span class="absolute text-green-500 right-0 bottom-0">
       <svg width="20" height="20">
          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="currentColor" class="absolute right-0 w-4 h-4 bg-green-600 border-2 border-green-700 rounded-full top-2 animate-pulse"></circle>
       </svg>
    </span>
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="" class="w-10 sm:w-16 h-10 sm:h-16 rounded-full"/>
 </div>
 <div class="flex flex-col leading-tight">
    <div class="text-2xl mt-1 flex items-center">
      <span class="text-gray-700 mr-3">Seller Name</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span>
</div>
</>
```

***(In here at the seller name place I want to show the selected seller name.)According to the selected person I need to load his name in the above point "Seller Name", I expect to use React UseEffect. How can I do that ?***

UI :
[image]

Comment: you dont need useEffect to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving just the selected id of a person. You can easily get entire object. Change the person state to receive person object and use **setSelectPerson(item)** instead of **setSelectPerson(idx)**. Then, you can use any field of the object you want.

Sample example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-wright-6xrn0t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: how can I code the UseEffect for `setSelectPerson(item)` ?

Comment: I have added the UI also, I need to load seller's name according to selected chat

Comment: Do you really need to use useEffect? Since you are in the same render scope, just use person.sellerName as the value. In your code, just replace <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span> to <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">{person.sellerName}</span>

Comment: Please check the UI, I want to load the seller name according to selected chat....

Comment: I have created a sample example for you here:
[link]https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-wright-6xrn0t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Updated the sandbox to show you the way of using useEffect

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. This is the entire code, https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-paper-u2kp0d?file=/src/App.js   UI may not work but Json file and code is there.

Comment: change the line 523 from **selectedPerson.sellerName** to **selectedPerson?.sellerName**

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

you dont need  useEffect to do that, as said by `Md Wahidul Azam` in his answer you can easily get the person object ,just change your code as shown below,instead of id just set a item object

```
<div className="space-y-2">
{person.map((item, idx) => (
  <RadioGroup.Option
    key={item.id}
    value={item.id}
    onClick={() => setSelectPerson(item)}
    className={({ active }) =>
      `${
        active
          ? 'ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-red-300 ring-white ring-opacity-60 border-l-4 border-red-500'
          : ''
      }
        relative rounded-lg shadow-md px-5 py-4 cursor-pointer flex focus:outline-none entry cursor-pointer 
        transform hover:scale-105 duration-300`
    }
    
  >
```

now for **I want to show the selected seller name.**
use the selectPerson Object as shown  below in the code ,i assume both code are in same component

```
 <>
 <div class="relative">
<span class="absolute text-green-500 right-0 bottom-0">
   <svg width="20" height="20">
      <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="currentColor" class="absolute right-0 w-4 h-4 bg-green-600 border-2 border-green-700 rounded-full top-2 animate-pulse"></circle>
   </svg>
</span>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="" class="w-10 sm:w-16 h-10 sm:h-16 rounded-full"/>
</div>
<div class="flex flex-col leading-tight">
<div class="text-2xl mt-1 flex items-center">
  <span class="text-gray-700 mr-3">{selectPerson.sellerName}</span>
</div>
<span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span>
</div>
</>
```

Comment: Please check the UI according to the selected person I need to load his chatbox. check the last code section in that pace I want to load selected person data.

Comment: then inside useEffect you can make api call that fetch data of user and store inside state

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `person` array and the `selectPerson` state variable available, you should be able to reference the seller's name like this:

```
<>
 <div class="relative">
    <span class="absolute text-green-500 right-0 bottom-0">
       <svg width="20" height="20">
          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="currentColor" class="absolute right-0 w-4 h-4 bg-green-600 border-2 border-green-700 rounded-full top-2 animate-pulse"></circle>
       </svg>
    </span>
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="" class="w-10 sm:w-16 h-10 sm:h-16 rounded-full"/>
 </div>
 <div class="flex flex-col leading-tight">
    <div class="text-2xl mt-1 flex items-center">
      <span class="text-gray-700 mr-3">{person[selectPerson].sellerName}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span>
</div>
</>
```

Depending where your `<RadioGroup>` is relative to the bottom block of code you shared, you may need to [lift](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) `selectPerson` and `setSelectPerson` up to a parent.

Comment: my problem is how to select a person and view the data using `UseEffect`, I have added the UI also here please help me to load the selected chat's person name, as an example the chat box seller name should be "Ryann Remo"

Comment: Where/why are you trying to use `useEffect`?

Comment: Please check the UI in the left side chat I'm going to select a person. then according to that I want to load chat data.

Comment: You can do that without useEffect if you are passing `person` and `selectPerson` as props